# Simplify javascript object creation using ES6 destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is there a way to simplify the update of the user object using destructuring where I have an old object and I want to update to the new object with the same names for the properties.

I want to use the same user object and update the values rather than creating a new object.

```
function UpdateUserProps(user, updatedUser) {
    const { email, status } = updatedUser;
    user.email = email;
    user.status = status;
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it without destructuring as well using `Object.assign`

```
function updateUserProps(user, updatedUser) {
 return Object.assign({}, user, updatedUser);
}
```

If you want to update in the same user object

```
function updateUserProps(user, updatedUser) {
 return Object.assign(user, updatedUser);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use spread syntax `...` in object. This creates a new object.

```js
function UpdateUserProps(user, updatedUser) {
  return {...user, ...updatedUser}
}
```

You can also use parameter destructuring to take specific properties from update object.

```js
function UpdateUserProps(user, {email, status}) {
  return {...user, ...{email, status}}
}

let user = {
  name: "foo",
  email: "foo",
  status: true
}

console.log(UpdateUserProps(user, {
  email: "bar",
  status: false
}))
```

Comment: Brilliant, what about if I didn't want all the properties of updatedUser, just the ones that matched user, is that possible?

Comment: If you want to check each property of update if it exists in user i think you need loop for that, but if you know what properties to take upfront then you could use param destructuring https://jsfiddle.net/321vqep8/16/